# wkhtmltopdf, how to use relative path images when use stdin

Tags: linux, wkhtmltopdf

files: sample.html, image.jpg.

sample.html:

```
...
<img src='image.jpg'/>
...
```

cmd:

`cat sample.html | wkhtmltopdf - output.pdf`

image can't display.

Comment: This kind of question should be posted to superuser.com instead.

Comment: but I use it in my project, it is also a programming problem

Comment: This *type* of question should be asked on superuser.com but I'm not going to offend them by migrating this there. Please go to superuser.com and post a much fuller and complete question, with more description, text, what you experienced, etc. Did you look at the file produced? Is it an image file? In any case, I'm closing this question here as not a question.

Comment: This kind of question does get asked sometimes. It has to do with wkhtmltopdf usage and my answer usually is very much related to programming. I just answered one Q like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963579/

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am a programmer looking for a solution to this question, I personally feel theres plenty of detail in this question to figure out whats going on ... I believe this to be incorrectly closed

Comment: The key words there is *figure out*. Nobody should have to *figure out* what the question is, that question should be *asked*. You're however free to flag the question for reopening.

Comment: I would say it's very badly worded, and maybe should be migrated, but all the information is there. It just needs someone to rewrite it. "wkhtmltopdf, how to use relative path images when use stdin" -> "How can I use stdin with wkhtmltopdf and relative images paths?"

Comment: It's not vague at all when you're experiencing the problem... I'm looking for an answer to this too.