# Images in Html to PDF using wkhtmltopdf in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to convert html to pdf. I am using mvc 4. I was able to convert html to pdf. The only problem I have is that images do not render. There is small rectangle where image should appear. I have my images in database so when I get html string in my controller this is how image is shown right before I pass this string to converter:

```
<img src="/Images/Image/GetImageThumbnail?idImage=300" alt=""/>
```

So I am thinking that this approach is not working becuase I pass string to converter so image cannot be rendered. Any ideas how to solve this problem if images are in db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve a similar issue by replacing src from `src="/img/derp.png"` to `src="http://localhost/img/derp.png"`. I get the host part from the request that my Controller receives.

```
// Here I'm actually processing with HtmlAgilityPack but you get the idea
string host = request.Headers["host"];
string src = node.Attributes["src"].Value;
node.Attributes["src"].Value = "http://" + host + src;
```

This means that the server must be also be able to vomit images directly from URLs like that.

I guess it could be done with string.Replace as well if your HTML is in a string

```
string host = request.Headers["host"];
html = html.Replace("src=\"/", "src=\"http://"+host+"/"); // not tested
```

Comment: Wooohoooo....it works...I have just added http://www.mydomain.com/Images/Image/GetImageThumbnail?idImage=300 in image src. I already give up and tried to pass view as direct url to wkhtmltopdf but this solution is much nicer. Tnx.

Comment: I tried dozens of proposed solutions to this issue. This is the only one that works (besides full path - src="http://mysite.com/img/derp.png).